# At the time of cropping image i face some error like "not enough values to unpack"

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, opencv

I'm trying to **Crop an Image and plot** into `matplotlib.pyplot`using python but it shows an Error

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("tt.jpg")
type(image)
print(image.shape)
W = 100
H = 100
def crop_center(img , cropx , cropy):
    y,x,c = image.shape
    startx = x//2-(cropx//2)
    starty = y//2-(cropy//2)
    return img[starty:starty+cropy , startx:startx+cropx]
croped = crop_center(image,W,H)
print(croped)
print(plt.imshow(croped, cmap='gray'))
plt.show() # with scaled size
```

** Error:**

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openimage.py", line 96, in <module>
  croped = crop_center(scaled,W,H)
  File "openimage.py", line 92, in crop_center
  y,x,c = image.shape
  ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables. This helps to find problem.

Comment: why do you use `x` two times in `y,x,x = ...` ?

Comment: it is your problem `y,x,x = ...` . You need `y,x,z = ...` or `y,x,_ = ...`

Comment: Instead of adding “solved” to the title, consider writing an answer with your solution, it might be useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method to Crop your image.

`y_start` in this code means for height in image from top where you want to crop and `y_end` is for bottom of image in this case `y_start` is `0` and `y_end` is `100` means height will remain **same as original**.

`x_start` and `x_end` work same as i mentioned above and in this case it will start cropping from `30%` to `60%` means after cropping you will get **center part of image**.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('imagename.jpg')
height, width, channels = img.shape
h_p = height/100
w_p = width/100
y_start = 0 # Put your value  
y_end = 100 # Put your value
x_start = 30 # Put your value
x_end = 60 # Put your value
img = img[int((y_start)*h_p):int((y_end)*h_p), int((x_start)*w_p):int((x_end)*w_p)]
cv2.imshow("left", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```